# Bluetooth low energy system design, response protocol

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I currently have a bluetooth low energy peripheral device (written in swift, an OSX machine) with a single service. The service has two characteristics, one that is to be written to by a central device (Android) with a string representing a command, and another that the peripheral writes to with a response corresponding to the command it has received.

The question I have is this: is that a normal way to go about this? Or is there a better way to respond to a write from the central device?

I am also having some trouble writing the Android side of this, I have been using BLE Scanner to test and it has worked perfectly but I cannot find the source of an example that works similarly.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this but it is not the normal way.It is also basically how you see the data exchange. BLE is designed in a way where the Slave (peripheral) provides different characteristics where you write and read data on the Slave(like a register) or the slave sends notifications to inform the master about changes.
Your response will be written in your second characteristic and you will read it out with the Ble Scanner or? So this is not a "real response sending" you just write the data and read from the Master.
The Master have always to send a request to the Slave.(except notifications)

I hope this helps you.

br

Comment: Essentially the master sends a command that is parsed by the slave, and the slave responds with a message specific to the request specified by said command. There are MANY different commands and responses set up right now, do you think I should re-write each command response as it's own characteristic? For instance, I send DEV_00 GET_NAME and receive DEV_00 NAME="SampleName" ... should SampleName be stored as a characteristic?

Comment: and the main reason I'd prefer not to do this is because the way it is set up now works nicely over USB (serial UART), and my goal is simply to convert this protocol to bluetooth.

Comment: Yes exactly, Further there are already predefined characterstics exact for this. Look at [this](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicsHome.aspx) There is a list of all bluetooth specifified characatersitics. Also Device name is already defined by Bluetooth SIG so you can use this.